# Magento 2 Too many password reset requests even when password reset protection is disabled

Tags: magento2.2.2, change-password

I logged in as administrator to Magento backend and trying to reset password for some customers.

I have **disabled password protection** from Configuration -> Customers -> customer configuration. so it look like this in my admin,

[image]

I have cleared cache. But I still get the same error "Too many password reset requests, please wait and try again".

What did I miss?

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue but for me there was an option where I can set the minimum Time between password reset requests as shown below.[image: Admin Config]

In my case, **it was set to 10 min**. After **I change it to 0** the issue was resolved.
 The configuration exists in the same path as you have mentioned but not sure why you do not have this configuration in your Magento.

Comment: He also has this setting just need to set password reset protection type to by ip and email only then These options will show

Answer (score 1):

You can try to disable:

- Max Number of Password Reset Requests
- Min Time Between Password Reset Requests

with:

```shell
bin/magento config:set customer/password/max_number_password_reset_requests 0
bin/magento config:set customer/password/min_time_between_password_reset_requests 0
```

then clean cache:

```shell
bin/magento c:c
```