# Cannot reset password many times

Tags: magento2

First, I reset password for account A => Success

After 5 seconds, I reset password for account B => Failed, error message is "We received too many requests for password resets. Please wait and try again later or contact abc@email.com"

If I reset password for account B after about 5 minutes => Success

I found that when the time between 2 reset password processes is too short, the exception called SecurityViolationException appeared

I want to able to reset password for account B after 5 seconds from reset password for account A, can I fix to do that?

Comment: Check this https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/password-options.html and this one also https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230527/magento-2-too-many-password-reset-requests-even-when-password-reset-protection-i

Comment: There is no real world scenario when one user will try to reset 2 different account passwords. So, for security reasons I believe you should not try to change this behavior.

Comment: Have you checked if the password reset limit and protection are set to be active either on ip and email or just ip in the admin?

Comment: Thanks all guy, I found that I can config in Store -> Configuration. Btw, nice support of all :D